# Run as Administrator popup via Skype for Business drops remote connection

Tags: remote-access, skype-for-business-2016

Does anybody know why Skype for Business drops connection on situations where a remote computer asks Administrator rights?  As soon as the user enters cancel the connection is retrieved. How to prevent that?

We are trying to use Skype for Business on simple administrative tasks on our AD-network. Usually we use this when a person is located in a remote location. Administrator could see and control remote computers and enter passwords etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a security feature implemented by Microsoft, you can't disable it, there is no work around through it.

Further reading: http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2014/10/lyncdevq-lync-shared-desktop-and-admin-control-with-uac/

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is old but the answer is incorrect. Using GPO you can set the UAC mode so the prompt appears but doesn't blank out the desktop.  If you are comfortable with that, the following GPO will allow you to respond to UAC prompts from a SfB remote session:

Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Local Policies/Security Options

User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation

Set to Disabled.

Comment: Answer from burto is not correct. This change allows remote users to SEE the UAC prompt, but not interact with any elevated processes. They'll be able to see the elevated programs, but not interact with them in any way, defeating the purpose.

Comment: The above also requires Computer Configuration/Windows Settings/Local Policies/Security Options "User Account Control: Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop" Enabled; to go along with "User Account Control: Switch to the secure desktop when prompting for elevation" Disabled.